# How to add custom preview urls for some pages?

Tags: api, previews

I use WordPress as a headless CMS through its API.

When clicking on `Preview` it takes me to `domain/slug`. This works for most of the pages, however there are some pages that are under sub-path `domain/sub-path/slug`.

How to enable the `Preview` button to take the user to the correct url? I use ACF, could that be utilised somehow to provide optional value for 'sub-path'?

Comment: Don't have an answer, but what's the sub-path referring to? e.g. is it the name of a category or some other taxonomy?

Comment: Well, that's not in the Wordpress side of the app. It is at the React frontend side, which fetches `pages` from WP API then some of those are under the root (/) and some under a sub-path (/something/). I'm not an experienced WP user/programmer but I assume a custom (ACF) field could be added to `pages` and then somehow use its value where the preview button is rendered. What do you think? Thanks!